# How can we install Hyperledger Bevel and Hyperledger Fabric in windows 11 system?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i want to develop to design a secure supply chain based on hyperledger . My question is what the process steps of installation of hyperledger Beval and Hyperledger Fabric in windows 11 system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer advice for Hyperledger Bevel, but for Fabric, I recommend setting up an Ubuntu Linux image using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). Then [install and run Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) within that Ubuntu environment following the instructions for running on Linux, including installing prerequisites in the Ubuntu environment.

In addition to the main Fabric documentation, this workshop material may also be useful:

https://github.com/hyperledgendary/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide/